# What's wrong with javascript string search?

Tags: javascript, string

Why this snippet does not generate 6? and generates -1?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    res =('{"name_^":"Ali","age":34}'.search('_^'));
    document.body.innerHTML = res ;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because [String.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) accepts regex, and `^` has a special meaning in regex.

Comment: Try `.search('_\\^')`

Comment: Or `.search(/_\^/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the indexOf function:

```
'{"name_^":"Ali","age":34}'.indexOf('_^')
```

returns 6
(search uses regex, and ^ has a special meaning in regex- -1 simply means the string wasn't found)

Answer (score 1):

`search` takes a regex. What you are trying to do is usually solved by `indexOf` - however, below would work:

```
let res ='{"name_^":"Ali","age":34}'.search(/_\^/);
console.log(res);
```

Or to make it good

```
let res ='{"name_^":"Ali","age":34}'.indexOf('_^');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the character so that it wont be read as a regex but as a simple char:
`search("_\\^")`
This gives `6` instead of `-1`.

Comment: While this does work, it's super confusing and unnecessarily cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because char ^ in Regex has a meaning and the js function search takes your input as a regex.

If you escape the ^ char it works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    res =('{"name_^":"Ali","age":34}'.search('_\\^'));
    document.body.innerHTML = res ;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```